# Routes getting appended in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, store, router

```
<Provider store = {store}>
        <Router history = {history} >
           <section>
                <Route path="/" component={DealList}/>
                <Route path="/deal" component={FormDeal}/>
                <Footer/>
           </section>
      </Router>
      </Provider>
```

I have this react router setup
Now if i call /deal , then the result is the combination of / and /deal path.
What is going wrong here

Comment: Check the [Route docs for exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

Comment: switch is what will be useful to you. Along with it as @bennygenel suggested, you can make use of `exact` keyword